# Control Point Layer Symbol placement with MapServer

Tags: labeling, symbology, mapserver

I have a point layer that are representing the location and type of traffic signs. The type of sign is a number code specified for each feature within the attribute table. I also have SVG graphics of all the signs. Unfortunately, in a lot of locations there are more than one sign set up (or in other terms some features have the same location). That means that the symbols (e.g. traffic sign graphics) will be overlapping or overlaying each other.

What I am trying to accomplish is to place, let's say, all three signs located on the same spot, AROUND the actual position. So that all signs are visible and not overlapping each other. Maybe add a leader pointing to the correct location.

In my Code I used the `LABEL` function with the STYLE option since it has a `POSITION` command, but for some reason if I am using a Symbol (the svg-graphics) instead of a text label the auto placement is not working and the symbols will be placed exactly on top of each other.

How can I control that symbols at the same location (but different `CLASS`es) will not be overlapping each other? Here is the Code I am using. For this purposes, I just added four Classes.

Originally there are over 300 of them and I am working with an INCLUDE file.

```
LAYER
    NAME            "DB001243"
    TOLERANCE       7
    TOLERANCEUNITS  PIXELS
    EXTENT          554157 6002172 598545 6040679
    DUMP            true
    TEMPLATE        fooOnlyForWMSGetFeatureInfo
    METADATA
        "wms_title"             "NAME"
        "wms_srs"               "EPSG:25832 EPSG:31467 EPSG:4326 EPSG:900913 EPSG:31468 EPSG:3857"
        "wfs_srs"               "EPSG:25832 EPSG:31467 EPSG:4326 EPSG:900913 EPSG:31468 EPSG:3857"
        "wms_include_items"     "all"           ## Invnr wurde rausgenommen

        "gml_include_items"         "all,geometry"          ## Invnr wurde rausgenommen
        "gml_geometries"            "geometry"
        "gml_geometry_type"         "point"
    END
    TYPE    POINT
    STATUS ON
    DATA  "DB001243"
    CLASSITEM "Stvoznr"
    LABELCACHE ON
    
    ## Sign 1 ##
    CLASS 
        EXPRESSION '1000-10' 
        LABEL
            STYLE 
               SYMBOL '1000-10' 
               SIZE 20 
            END
            FORCE false
            POSITION    auto
            PARTIALS FALSE
        END
    END
    
    ## Sign 2 ##
    CLASS 
        EXPRESSION '505-22' 
        LABEL
            STYLE 
               SYMBOL '505-22' 
               SIZE 20 
            END
            FORCE false
            POSITION    auto
            PARTIALS FALSE
        END
    END
    
    ## Sign 3 ##
    CLASS 
        EXPRESSION '229-30' 
        LABEL
            STYLE 
               SYMBOL '229-30' 
               SIZE 20 
            END
            FORCE false
            POSITION    auto
            PARTIALS FALSE
        END
    END

    ## Sign 4 ##
    CLASS
        NAME    "other signs"
        MAXSCALEDENOM 100000
        LABEL
            STYLE
                COLOR       "#000000"                   
                SIZE        8
                SYMBOL      "circle"                
                OUTLINECOLOR    "#FF0000"
                WIDTH       1
            END
        POSITION    auto
        END
    END
    
    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
END
```